# Sign a PDF without using library in PHP (multiple signature)

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, digital-signature, signature

I want to add a signature to a PDF without using a library (or a package) in PHP. I tried to create custom data of a signature and add to the PDF like this:

```
    1 0 obj
    <<
    /Type /Catalog
    /Pages 1 0 R
    /Lang (en-US)
    /AcroForm <<
    /Fields [17 0 R]
    /SigFlags 3
    >>
    >>
    endobj
    17 0 obj
    <<
    /FT /Sig
    /Type /Annot
    /Subtype /Widget
    /F 132
    /T (Signature)
    /V 18 0 R
    /P 12 0 R
    >>
    endobj
    18 0 obj
    <<
    /Type /Sig
    /Reason <FEFF01101ED3006E0067002000FD0020006B00FD>
    /M (D:20210428175113+07'00')
    /Filter /Adobe.PPKLite
    /SubFilter /adbe.pkcs7.detached
    /ByteRange[0 13359 25103 267]                 /Contents <[signature value]>
    >>
    endobj
    xref
    0 2
    0000000000 65535 f 
    0000012934 00000 n 
    17 2
    0000013042 00000 n 
    0000013145 00000 n 
    trailer
    << /Size 19 /Root 14 0 R /Info 15 0 R /ID [ <387f24f9aa90c81aff64b0c42cbe2f42> <387f24f9aa90c81aff64b0c42cbe2f42> ] >>
    /Prev 12409
    startxref
    25115
    %%EOF
```

(Size, Root, Info I get form lasted version PDF)
But it did not work.

I tried to find document for signature directory but not has document for this.

Is there any documentation or how I can get this working?

Comment: What do you actually mean by "signature" here? A cryptographic signature to verify the contents of the document? Or just a pic of some pencil scribbles?

Comment: Consider the pdf specification, ISO 32000-1 or ISO 32000-2.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you, "Signature" here has both meanings that you mean.

Comment: @mkl Thank you, I will read that document.

Comment: Adobe has provided a free copy of ISO 32000-1 for download, merely the ISO headers have been replaced. Just google for PDF32000